# How to properly override an abstract method with generics in the signature

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I thought I understood how to do this but I'm getting some unexpected behavior so apparently I'm missing something. Here's the problem boiled down.

Base Class:

```
public abstract class Base<T>
{
    abstract public void foo(List<? extends T> l);
}
```

Derived Class:

```
public class Derived<T> extends Base
{
    @Override
    public void foo(List<? extends T> l) { return; }
}
```

The Base class complies fine, but when I compile the Derived class I get:

> Derived.java:3: Derived is not abstract and does not override abstract method foo(java.util.List) in Base
>
> public class Derived extends Base
> ^
> Derived.java:5: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>
> ```
> @Override  
> ^
> ```
>
> 2 errors

The generics of the parameter `List<? extends T>` appears to be the cause of the problem. If I replace that part in both signatures with the basic type `int` it comples fine.

Can anybody tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should do

```
public class Derived<T> extends Base<T>
```

You need to specify `<T>` for `Base` otherwise you will have to override method by simply declaring `List` i.e.without generics

Comment: Wow, such a simple solution. I guess I'm used to the complier warnings when I forget to specify the type of a generic, but it doesn't give one in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass the type parameter in your class declaration like this:

```
    public class Derived extends Base<SomeConcreteType> {

        @Override
        public void foo(List<SomeConcreteType> l) {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

if you no longer need the generic part of the abstract class because you are going to use a concrete type in your derived class. Otherwise you have to do what the other answer stated.